# How to request xAuth privileges of my iPhone App for Custome Twitter Login UI?

Tags: ios4, twitter, xauth

In my application i want to use my own Login page for twitter login. I search around and i found tutorial and code for that http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/09/integrating-twitter-into-your-applications/ ,https://github.com/aral/XAuthTwitterEngine

i have gone through both of this code. but getting error like

> error : Client application is not permitted to use xAuth.

I serched for this error and found xAuth document on developer.twiiter here it is

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth

From this document i found that i have to sent a detailed message to **api@twitter.com** to request xAuth privileges. Include the name of my application, the consumer key, the application ID (if available), and a summary of how xAuth is best-suited for your application.

I have sent mail to **api.twitter.com** according they ask for.but i still not get xAuth Privilage to use my Custome Login UI.api.twitter reply my mail but there is nothing mention about my xAuth access that i have requested for. Here is reply from them

> ### - Please type your reply above this line -

Hello, This email is an automated response to acknowledge receipt of your email regarding xAuth access. Please note: for your application to qualify for xAuth access, it must be production-ready and only accessible via standalone desktop application or via mobile. We are not granting xAuth for test purposes, single-user applications, web-based applications, or for applications that are in the early stages of development. In order for your request to be processed, you must reply to this email with the following required information within 5 days: • Your App ID number (or consumer key) from dev.twitter.com/apps/ • A link to your application’s website • A link to a short video demonstrating the following: - Your application’s main features - How your application interacts with Twitter, including its user login functionality - a fully functional OAuth integration. Knowledge of OAuth is required to implement xAuth; we require your application have a fully working OAuth integration before we can grant this authentication privilege. • A link to a demo twitter account which has authorized access to your application’s OAuth integration and has used it. Please note that our ticketing system does not accept attachments; you will need to upload your video to your server or a video host (for example, YouTube or Vimeo) and provide a direct link (URL) to the video. You may remove the video if you so choose once your request has been processed and you have received our reply. If you provided the required information listed above in your initial request, please respond to this ticket to affirm that all required information is present. If you were not requesting access to xAuth but received this response, please let us know by responding to this ticket. If you have a technical question about the API, please visit our developer site, where you will find extensive documentation about the Twitter API: dev.twitter.com/docs. Thanks, Twitter API Policy

Now anyone can help me please how can i get xAuth access to use my custome UI for twitter Login?

help will appreciate lot. its really curd of mind....

thanx